# Swift - Change buttonframe in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, button

I'm trying to build an app in Xcode and implement buttons to the storyboard.

unfortunately the button frame is quite small in reference to the text inside. How to I change the frame into bigger?

As I am totally new to coding I have no idea - this is the code, but I don't know how to change the frame size and if this is even the right code.

```swift
extension UIButton {

    func applyDesign() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        self.frame.size =

}
```

Comment: Instead of changing frame, please check how to add constraint to button (which set frame) in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating buttons inside storyboard, you can simply use constraints for frames. If you want to do it manually like you mentioned then you can create a CGRect and assign it to frame, for example:

```
self.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 50, width: 170, height: 30)
```

Comment: Hey Bisma, thank you!

Unfortunately it says: 
Value of type '(CGRect) -> CGRect' has no member 'size'. 
How to I add the size?